# Yet another .sty not found problem, Ubuntu 22.04 + TeXLive-full

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu

I'm sorry if this has already been answered, but I am really getting tired of this kind of error. I am using TeXLive on a Ubuntu 22.04 system (I just did `sudo apt install texlive-full` to avoid missing anything). Then, I put a directory named `polytechnique` which contains a `polytechnique.sty` file in the `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/` directory. Using `locate` gave the following :

```sh
$ locate polytechnique.sty
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/polytechnique/polytechnique.sty
```

After that, I tried both `sudo texhash` and `sudo mktexlsr` which both outputed the following (except program name):

```sh
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

So apparently, `texmf-local` was handled and the package should be put in the database right ? Then, I wrote a `.tex` file with a `\usepackage{polytechnique}` directive. This is what happened next:

```sh
$ pdflatex file.tex
...
! LaTeX Error: File `polytechnique.sty' not found.
...
```

I sincerely have no idea how to solve this... any thoughts ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: show the begin of the log-file (until it reads e.g. article.cls).

Comment: what does `which pdflatex` report?

Comment: Welcome. You probably have two versions of TeX Live installed. I doubt `apt` installed anything into `/usr/local`. (At least, it shouldn't.) I'm guessing `PATH` is altered when you `sudo`. What do `echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` return?

Comment: you have the system texlive installed via aopt (which does not have the package) and a locally installed texlive that does have the package but you are not using that version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. I deleted my above comment. Use a jailed Linux on Android, which has some very unusual paths.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get exactly this:
```sh
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.3.30)  31 MAR 2024 20:34
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**file.tex
(./file.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

Comment: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist` is different to the path in your question `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist`. This looks as if you have two tex systems.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `which pdflatex` gives `/usr/bin/pdflatex`. I believe I have one texlive-full installation in `/usr/local/texlive/` (the fat dir that weighs 8 GB). I found it using `fdfind texlive /`. It seems this is not the texlive provided by apt, as apt is rather trying to put it in `/usr/share`. I did `sudo apt remove texlive-full && sudo apt autoremove`, which only deleted 4 GB of packages in `/usr/share`, with no effect on the compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then how do I solve this ? Do I move all the content of `/usr/local/texlive` to `/usr/share/texlive` ?

Comment: sorry I have no idea, I'm on windows.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is the system tex you installed via apt/   the one in `/usr/local` is normally in a dated subdirectory such as `/usr/local/texlive/2024` and is an upstream texlive installed from tug.

Comment: No never copy files intro system controlled directories such as /usr/bin and /usr/share by hand, you will confuse the linux package manager which won't know they are there and will overwrite things at some random update.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. Then, what to do ? apt cannot seem to remove these files alone with `apt remove texlive`...

Comment: what do you want to do?  the simplest thing is just leave the files apt installed and use the upstream texlive for which you just need to set the PATH as documented when you installed it so something like `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`  in your  `~/.profile` then log in again so it gets read.  then you will be using texlive from tug and can update it with `tlmgr` rather than `apt`  oh you have 2022 rather than 2024 so adjust the path, or install texlive 2024)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle truth is, I don't remember installing texlive with something else than apt... I will look at the doc for that online, thank you a lot !